# Plugin to add authentication for Grails application using Outlook Creds

Tags: authentication, grails, plugins, outlook

I am trying to implement authentication to our grails application which should use the outlook creds for authentication test. Is there any plugin for grails as such?

I found Grails plugin Authentication and Shiro but both seems for simple authentication which allows registration, but I am looking for the plugin which can be used to implement using outlook creds and no registrations from the web application.

Please suggest me, I might be wrong on above plugins... Thanks

Comment: What do you mean when you say "Outlook" credentials? Are you talking about Active Directory? Are you talking about Office365?

Comment: Outlook doesn't have any credentials. Are you talking about the mail profile credentials?

Comment: sorry for the unclear question... our company uses Oracle Access Management for Office Outlook mails , so want to use same for our application so no need of extra registration process... I want our application should be accessible to only our employees who have their Office mail access creds has set up

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Security plugin allows you to implement virtually any authentication mechanism you like. Although the default is based on a username and password stored in a database, it is fairly easy to replace this with something else.

[Here's a blog post](http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1090) from the Spring Security plugin author wherein he describes how to implement a custom authentication mechanism, a link to the sample application is provided at the end of the post.

Comment: @user1653027 I've implemented a custom Spring Security authentication mechanism myself, so can probably provide more detailed information if you need it.